# Go : How to ignore type mismatch error when json.Unmarshal to struct?

Tags: json, go

Assume I have a struct like

```
type A struct {
    Val1 int `json:"val1"`
    Val2 int `json:"val2"`
}
```

then:

```
str := `{"val1": "abc", "val2": 2}`
var a A
error := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString),&a)
```

How can I ingore `val1` type mismatch error? I just want to ignore errors when the types don’t match, and parse normally if they match.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I ingore val1 type mismatch error? I just want to ignore errors when the types don’t match, and parse normally if they match.

You cannot do that.

The best thing you can do is have the type e.g. `interface{}` or `json.Number` and decide later.